# Pandas get date difference between 2 ISO date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 date strings: `2020-02-12T16:02:51Z` and `2017-03-08T18:16:02-05:00`, and I'd like to get the difference in days that includes partial day difference (for example, a difference of 1 day 12 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds will be 1.5 days).

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.to_datetime("2020-02-12T16:02:51Z", utc=True)
date2 = pd.to_datetime("2017-03-08T18:16:02-05:00", utc=True)
diff = date1 - date2

diff.days
>>> 1070
```

I expect it should be `1070.<some decimal digits>`. Because `diff` is `Timedelta('1070 days 16:46:49')`

What did I do wrong? I am using Python 3.8.1 and pandas 1.0.1

Comment: timedelta object stores only days, seconds and microseconds. You can retrieve them using diff.days, diff.seconds, and diff.microseconds respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timedelta.days` represents the number of days in the delta. So, in your case `1070`.
 However, you have different options to get the results in fractional form.

```
>>> diff = date1 - date2
>>> diff.days + diff.seconds/86400
1070.6991782407408
>>> diff.total_seconds()/86400
1070.6991782407408
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong. `pandas.Timedelta.days` returns full days in the timedelta object. You can find fractional days with using `diff.value` (which returns nanoseconds), such as:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.to_datetime("2020-02-12T16:02:51Z", utc=True)
date2 = pd.to_datetime("2017-03-08T18:16:02-05:00", utc=True)
diff = date1 - date2

# nano seconds to days
diff.value / 8.64e+13
>>> 1070.6991782407408
```